# Is there a way to check video length in PhotosPicker immediately when user selects video from their gallery?

Tags: swift, swiftui, photospicker

I'm trying to limit the size of videos the user is allowed to upload. Is there a native way or workaround to check immediately in PhotosPicker if the user selects a video that exceeds a certain length? For example if we set a limit of 20 seconds, and a user selects a video at 25 seconds, we would trigger an action.

I did achieve this functionality, but only after I stored the video in storage and fetched the URL. It would be great to check this immediately once the user uploads and not have to fetch the URL first in order to achieve this.

Comment: What difference would this make to the user? The user experience would be the same wouldn't it?

Comment: @Sweeper User experience would be the same yes, but every time a user selects a video I'm saving that video to firestore's storage and grabbing the URL whether the user even wants to upload and save the video or not which is a pain

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phfetchoptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this. The picker doesn't hand you a video when the user merely taps on an item to selct it in the picker; in fact, it doesn't hand you *anything* until the user is *finished* with the picker (and even *then* it doesn't hand you any videos — you have to fetch them yourself). If you want a picker where you know what the user is doing while the user is interacting with the picker, you will have to write your *own* picker, from scratch.